# Linux spawn, expect, send

Tags: linux, expect

The following code isn't working, but what I want to do is answer *"n"* whenever **YUM** asks whether I want to install the software or not. Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn yum install emacs
expect "Is this ok \[y\/N\]:"
send "n\r"
```

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` at the top of the script and re-run. That will give you lots of debugging info

Answer (score 2):

Starting with your code snippet this is what I got to work

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

expect -c  "
    set timeout 15
    spawn yum install emacs

    expect {
        "]:"        { send n\r ; sleep 1 ; exp_continue  } 
    }
"
```

it also works with    `#!/bin/bash` at the top

Answer (score 1):

From the [yum manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum):

```
-y, --assumeyes
    Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be asked is yes.
    Configuration Option: assumeyes
```

So just use `yum -y` instead of messing around with `expect`.

Answer (score 0):

change the `expect "Is this ok \[y\/N\]:"`

to

expect "]:"

are you geting the same error? if not its a typo in your expect.